# How to broadcast an event to specific users with laravel and pusher api?

Tags: laravel, broadcast, pusher

My problem is broadcast an event to specific users. I am building a live chat app.
so this has private chat and group chat.

In one-to-one chat(private chat), if a user message to another user, broadcast new message to the target user, not all users. For now, broadcasting to all users.
As the same above, in group chat, I want targeting broadcast to the members who is in group.

here is my code.

laravel event

```
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use App\Message;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class NewMessage implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;
    public $message;
    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($message)
    {
        $this->message = $message;
        // $this->dontBroadcastToCurrentUser();
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new PrivateChannel('chats');
    }
}
```

Channel

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Broadcast;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Broadcast Channels
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may register all of the event broadcasting channels that your
| application supports. The given channel authorization callbacks are
| used to check if an authenticated user can listen to the channel.
|
*/

Broadcast::channel('App.User.{id}', function ($user, $id) {
    return (int) $user->id === (int) $id;
});
Broadcast::channel('chats', function ($user) {
    return auth()->check();
});
```

Comment: Did you try to, for example, create a `NewMessageToSpecificUser` event which broadcasts on `user.id`?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I know I should do something like that. but I cannot find a good tutorial or code block. 
Could you explain about this?

Comment: Well, it's basically the first example on the broadcasting documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/broadcasting#defining-broadcast-events

Comment: I will try. thanks.